# Specific flight pricing questions

Tags: discussion, good-questions, scope

So I wondered - I love helping people find better flight prices.  But I wondered if this is suitable for travel.SE - to have a question like:

"The cheapest flight from ULN to LON on xx/yy/zz I can find is $999 - can anyone beat this?"

This would have been especially useful for me last year in Bolivia when I had to take an emergency flight to New Zealand - last minute flights are NOT cheap :)

My feeling is we're all 'road-warriors' (or air-warriors?) and all have different sources - plus it increases competitiveness to find the best price available ;)

Comment: I think this is probably a good example of where the "too specific" rule might actually come into play on travel.SE since the timeframe is likely to be small and the answers will quickly go out of date and be unhelpful for future Google searches.

Comment: Specific day may be "too specific"; week/month timeframes should be okay?

Answer (score 8):

Specific price questions are not really well-suited for this type of Q&A.

The purpose of this site is to build up a canon of knowledge about traveling. The life of a question is generally expected to go well beyond the original author and the person answering the question. Very specific pricing questions really cannot help anyone but that specific user in that specific case in that specific point in time. That is the very definition of "too localized."

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Comment: See also this meta discussion: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/are-questions-that-will-go-out-of-date-on-topic-for-this-site

Answer (score 7):

I would like to see questions that lead to answers that show how in general to find the lowest price. Of course, the rules contradict each other. So maybe one question leads to good answers about how prices go up and down over the year and when seat sales are. Another leads to information about "alternate airports" that can save you a ton - or how that LCC doesn't fly where you think, it's 100 miles away and there's no reliable public transport to where you want to be. And so on.